# Cross Domain 301 Redirect URL With Spaces

Tags: redirect, mod-rewrite, dns, http-status-code-301

I am having serious trouble redirecting a URL in the following format:

oldsite.com/file name.htm to newsite.com/newfilename.htm

Apache server with mod_rewrite etc enabeled - other 301s working fine (i.e. 301s redirecting urls without spaces)

I have tried numerous solutions and went through pretty much every answer on stackoverflow.

Any help is greatly appreciated - need to get this sorted out before I pull the last of my hair out!!

Thanks guys!

EDIT: This is the code I am using successfully to redirect all URLs that DO NOT have spaces.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewriterule ^somedirectory/solutions.htm(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/new-solutions/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Comment: Please provide some code you tried to help us improve that.

Comment: Could you describe what the problem you're having is? All we know is you've got "serious trouble" redirection the URL. I'm guessing that the server isn't matching your "...file name.htm", have you tried URL encoding? %20 for space. And what does having mod_rewrite have to do with anything? It seems you want to redirect, not rewrite, which I believe is mod_alias.

Comment: Tried: including %20 in the redirect code, tried escaping the spaces etc.  All other redirects working fine so no issue with mod_alias or mod_rewrite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried escaping the space in your rewrite or redirection rule? Example below.

```
oldsite.com/file\ name.htm
```

Ok perhaps try this. Note, this is just for that specific page.

```
redirect 301 "/file name.htm" http://newsite.com/newfilename.htm
```

Comment: Nicely done Pjack - its working perfectly. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Spaces are encoded as `%20` in URLs:

```
oldsite.com/file%20name.htm
```